# Custom Openai Gym Environment with Stable-baselines

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I am trying to create a simple 2D grid world Openai Gym environment which agent is headed to the terminal cell from anywhere in the grid world. For example, in the 5x5 grid world, X is the current agent location and O is the terminal cell where agent is headed to.

```
.....
.....
..X..
.....
....O
```

My action space is defined to discrete value [0,4) which represents up, left, down and right respectively. And, the observation space is a 1D box which denotes the agent current position in the grid world for example [12] (index start from 0 to size*size-1). I am wondering what are the differences between ways of defining the observation space. For example, other than my current definition, an observation space for the same environment can be defined as follow, just to named a few.

1. discrete value of i, which i represents the current location of agent.
2. a 2d matrix with all zero except the agent current location which is 1.
3. maybe others how are these different in term of stable-baselines algorithm or others?

Answer (score 0):

**What are the differences between ways of defining the observation space?**

I think the better question is:

***What are the reason for differences between ways of defining the observation space?***

In order to defining the observation space, two thing need to be determined:

1. What information algorithm need?

   This is largely determined by what information you can collect and agents objective, e.g if you want agent to reach the target in a maze, then you may provide info like current location of agent, obstacles direction around agent, target direction, etc.
2. What form the input information should be?
   This is largely determined by what information you use and agents solution(i.e algorithm itself), sometime you have multiple choices and you need run experiments to find out which work best for given algorithm, just like the few you listed.

So in general, reason of different ways to defining the observation space is for better suit different objective and algorithm.